# R markdown - how can I remove additional brackets around year in cited articles?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm preparing a document in which I cite more than one article. I wish to place all of them in one brackets, for example:

It was mentioned in (article1; article2;, article 3).

Unfortunately I noticed that RMarkdown adds brackets around year:

[image: brackets around year]

How can I remove them?

My document:

````
---
title: Additional brackets around year in citations
author:
  - name: Mateusz Kędzior
    email: alice@sample.com
    affiliation: WUT
    footnote: Corresponding Author
abstract: |
  First line

  The second line

keywords: some \sep thing \sep some \sep where
bibliography: listb.bib # I get .bib file from http://shelah.logic.at/eindex.html
csl: elsevier-harvard.csl # I get style from: https://www.zotero.org/styles/
link-citations: true

output:
   bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# What I receive

Cite only one article: @Sh:2

It was mentioned in: @Sh:1, @Sh:2, @Sh:3

It was mentioned in [ @Sh:1, @Sh:2, @Sh:3 ]

# Expected result

I wish to have something like:

It was mentioned in (Shelah, 1969b; Shelah, 1969a; Shelah, 1970)

# References
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format:

```
It was mentioned in [@barras2010a; @barras2010b; @barras2010c]
```

In other words, I would rename your id names to something like: `Sh1`, `Sh2`, `Sh3`, and say:

```
It was mentioned in [@Sh1; @Sh2; @Sh3]
```

Here's your revised example (with my example references):

````
---
title: Additional brackets around year in citations
author:
  - name: Mateusz Kędzior
    email: alice@sample.com
    affiliation: WUT
    footnote: Corresponding Author
output:
   html_document
references:
- id: barras2010a
  title: False Discoveries in Mutual Fund Performance - Measuring Luck in Estimated Alphas
  author:
  - family: Barras
    given: Lauren
  - family: Scaillet
    given: Olivier
  - family: Wermers
    given: Russ
  container-title: Journal of Finance
  volume: 65
  URL: 'http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01527.x/abstract'
  DOI: 10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01527.x
  page: 179-216
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2010
    month: February
- id: barras2010b
  title: False Discoveries in Mutual Fund Performance - Measuring Luck in Estimated Alphas
  author:
  - family: Barras
    given: Lauren
  - family: Scaillet
    given: Olivier
  - family: Wermers
    given: Russ
  container-title: Journal of Finance
  volume: 65
  URL: 'http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01527.x/abstract'
  DOI: 10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01527.x
  page: 179-216
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2010
    month: February
- id: barras2010c
  title: False Discoveries in Mutual Fund Performance - Measuring Luck in Estimated Alphas
  author:
  - family: Barras
    given: Lauren
  - family: Scaillet
    given: Olivier
  - family: Wermers
    given: Russ
  container-title: Journal of Finance
  volume: 65
  URL: 'http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01527.x/abstract'
  DOI: 10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01527.x
  page: 179-216
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2010
    month: February
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# What I receive

Cite only one article: @barras2010a

It was mentioned in: @barras2010a, @barras2010b, @barras2010c

It was mentioned in [@barras2010a; @barras2010b; @barras2010c]

# Expected result

I wish to have something like:

It was mentioned in (Shelah, 1969b; Shelah, 1969a; Shelah, 1970)

# References
````

And here's what it shows:

It was mentioned in (Barras, Scaillet, and Wermers 2010a; Barras, Scaillet, and Wermers 2010b; Barras, Scaillet, and Wermers 2010c)

I hope that helps you.